# Android POST request with JSON Constraint

Tags: java, android, python, mysql

[Error which i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiOpW.png)

The Error Tells me on class execution to create and inner class or create a new class

But i am executing it inside a button which is in onCreate method so please if anybody can guide me how to proceed ....

The Main Class

private class SendDeviceDetails extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String data = "";

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("PostData=" + params[1]);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
            while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                data += current;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("TAG", result); // this is expecting a response code to be sent from your server upon receiving the POST data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `()` after `newSendDeviceDetails`. It should be like the line below:

```
new newSendDeviceDetails().execute(...);
```

Comment: Thanks Soheil very much appreciated but i was dumb enough to miss single brackets after seeing the whole code